# how to prevent multiple submit on payment module?

Tags: magento

I would like to know how to prevent a user submit a payment more than once on Magento.

The problems begins when the payment fails, then the user can go back (back button on browser) and try again multiple times.

```
if($response == 3 || $responsecode == 300){
    $this->cancelAction();
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError("Invalid payment ".$responsetext.". Try again.");
    Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('checkout/onepage/failure', array('_secure'=>true));
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Is this a standard magento onepage checkout? At what stage is it failing (i.e. Final order submit stage, the one after payment)? Why would you not want to allow the user to retry if it failed??? Annoying user experience to re-add all products again... If you really want this functionality, you could simply empty the cart on failure with below answer.

Comment: Yes, it is a standard. The main reason is that some users are trying to make fraud. For example, if the payment failure screen appears, they goes back and change a number of the credit card number and try again. They repeat the process with the same order.

Answer (score 0):

You could empty the users cart which would mean they have to add products again;

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->truncate()->save();
```

Or maybe redirect to cart page and show error there so they have to go through whole checkout process again;

```
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('checkout/cart', array('_secure'=>true));
```